# Posix Pthread mutual exclusion

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I have written my issue in comments in the code.

I am trying to make my code parallel by using pthreads.
First I want to write a bulk of data in memory by several threads in parallel.
After writing the data, I want to execute this data by same threads.
And after executing the data, I want to read it. 
And after these three operations, I want to pass this data to other files. 
And I want to repeat this process several times.

I would really appreciate any of your help.
Thank you.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 100
#define NUMTHREADS 7

struct ThreadData {
    int start, stop, id;
    int* array;
};

/* function to write, execute and read data */
void* cal(void* td) {
    struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td;
    int start=data->start;
    int stop=data->stop;
    int thread_id = data ->id;
    int i,s, counter;
    counter = 0;

    //main loop
    for (s=0; s<200; s++){

        // in this loop1, I want to write data here by all the threads
        for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
    printf("thread %d is writing data\n", thread_id);
        }

        //in this loop2, after data written by all the threads in loop1,
        // data is execuated by all threads in this loop2 
        for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
    printf("thread %d is executing data\n", thread_id);
        }

        //in this loop3, data is read after completion of 
        // writing and execution in loop1 and loop2
        for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
    printf("thread %d is reading data\n", thread_id);
        }

        // counter, I want this counter to be executed only once 
        // per iteration after writing, executing and reading data.
        counter = counter +1;
    printf ("Value of counter is %d\n", counter); 

    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[ARRAYSIZE];
    pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
    struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
    int i;

    int tasksPerThread=(ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;

    /* Divide work for threads, prepare parameters */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].array=array;
        data[i].id = i;
    }
    /* the last thread must not go past the end of the array */
    data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;

    /* Launch Threads */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, cal, &data[i]);
    }

    /* Wait for Threads to Finish */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you can do that by using semaphores (http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html)

Comment: But in my opinion you should use different threads for each loop.

Comment: Also notice that for reading you don't need mutual exclusion

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I guess it's how he can make all threads wait till them all finish one loop, and then go for the next one.

Comment: thanks for replies. @user3198050 thanks for the info. Yes, u r right. I want to wait till all threads write in loop1 then want to execute data by SAME threads.(I have to use same threads for all the operation as later on I want to run each thread on different core of cpu). I had a look at the link u provided for semaphore but it doesnt have answer of my problem. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: @JensGustedt: My question is how to wait for all threads in cal function in above code. I want to start executing loop2 only after all threads executes loop1. Also, counter should be incremented only once per iteration of main loop. Thank you for looking at my code and giving time.@Jens Gustedt

Comment: See [pthread_barrier_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) and related functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need mutual exclusion only for counter so do a thread synchronization step before it and that should be enough.